# Excel Macro for vlookup Various Questions: change #n/a to zero; directly find lookup value and paste value of result

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded a vlookup macro to get the r1c1 formula and then wrote a simple macro to apply the formula for an entire column range.  See code below

Information:
 •I have a reconciliation tab with unique IDs listed in column starting on row 6.   Amount of IDs or rows is variable meaning it could always change but it is currently around 15000 IDs.  This is an all inclusive list of IDs.  The IDs is a continuous list.  There is no break in between.  Keep in mind that I have a Grand Total Row a few rows below the last ID populated.
•I have a second sheet within the same workbook that contains the same type of IDs in column A with various amounts in columns C through I - second sheet is called 'Aged AR'.  Not all the IDs may be included in this sheet as this tab represents a different type of reporting.

I have developed the following code to create a Vlookup on the reconciliation tab starting column D row 6 to pull in the amount in column C (3rd column) of the 2nd worksheet 'Aged AR' and apply it to the entire range of rows in column D as far down as the last ID populated in column A.  The array or look up range is looking up on the 'Aged AR' tab from column selects all of column A through I since I will apply this formula on the reconciliation tab for the range starting in column H6 and pull in the amounts in Column H on the 'Aged AR' sheet.

Questions:
 1.How can I expand on the code to change the #N/A result to a zero value?
2.How can I have all the results leave the cells formatted as value instead of leaving the vlookup formula?
3. With this loop, how do I continue it to do the same type of loop in column H starting at H6 on the recon tab looking up the 8th column in the vlookup array set on the 2nd sheet 'Aged AR'?
3.I anticipate the loop will cause the macro to take a while since I will be applying this type of formula once my project is complete to six columns and there are many rows.  All my reference sheets in my workbook contains the same type of IDs.  Is there a way to pull the referenced information and populate it where I want it designated on the 'reconciliation' sheet without using a vlookup formula.  Will it make the macro work more efficient?

I've spent yesterday and this morning reading different examples but I haven't been able to notice something that I can learn from since I'm a complete amateur to using VBA

```
Sub findit()

Dim oRange As Range
 Dim rec As Worksheet


'reconciliation tab contains ID's in column A
 Set rec = Sheets("Reconciliation")

'Located the end of the range I would like to populate in column D by finding the last row of IDs in column A

Set oRange = rec.Range(rec.Range("D6"), rec.Range("A6").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3))

'apply the vlookup formula to using each ID as a lookup value in column A and populating the result in column D for as far down as the IDs are populated

For Each cell In oRange

'vlookup formula is actually =vlookup(A6,'Aged Ar'!$A!:$I,3,false)

'where the lookup value A6 will increase to A7, A8,....n where n is the last row of IDs as it is applied to each row below starting at "D6"

cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Aged AR'!C1:C9,3,FALSE)"

Next cell

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I didn't realize when I copied the macro it came out in that format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use more efficient code:

```
With oRange
    .Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6,'Aged Ar'!$A:$I,3,FALSE),0)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

instead your `For Each` loop:

```
For Each cell In oRange

'vlookup formula is actually =vlookup(A6,'Aged Ar'!$A:$I,3,false)

'where the lookup value A6 will increase to A7, A8,....n where n is the last row of IDs as it is applied to each row below starting at "D6"

cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Aged AR'!C1:C9,3,FALSE)"

Next cell
```

1) this code change the #N/A result to a zero value (`IFERROR` function)

2) cells formatted as value instead of leaving the vlookup formula (`.Value = .Value` statement)

3) this code will make the macro work more efficient

4) A6 will increase to A7, A8,....n for corresponding rows

Comment: I feel some what of an idiot.  I did something similar using With/End With on a different code.  My problem is I don't know the languange enough to correlate like situations.  This works a lot better.  Question:  is the "With oRange   .formula........" part of the statement equivalent to "oRange.formula....."?

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your assistance really allowed me advance in my project.  That helped me tremendously and I learned quite a bit.